# Adding a computed column in Postgres SQL based on a date

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here my table.

```
CREATE TABLE annual_goals (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
  content TEXT NOT NULL,
  complete BOOLEAN DEFAULT false,
  date_created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now() NOT null,
  date_modified TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now() NOT null
);
```

I want to alter it such that I can add a new column called month_num that returns the number of the month given date_created (i.e. if the date_created of an entry is 5/31/2019, I want the month_num to automatically populate 5).

I tried the following but I'm getting an error that states "ERROR:  syntax error at or near "A
S"

```
ALTER TABLE annual_goals
    ADD year_num
        AS year(date_created);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL? It doesn't use `IDENTITY`, it uses `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Comment: And that's also not how it reports syntax errors. Maybe you're using SQL-Server?

Comment: It's not SQL Server either. Postgres, maybe, from the `PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT` syntax?

Comment: Ah, I am using postgres

Answer (score 1):

You have two errors in the code.  One is that MySQL requires the type.  The second is that the expression needs to be surrounded by parentheses:

```
ALTER TABLE annual_goals ADD year_num int AS ( year(date_created) );
```

EDIT:

In Postgres, you can use the syntax:

```
alter table annual_goals
    add year_num int generated always as (extract(year from date_created)) stored;
```

[Here](http://2&fiddle=a0401c79c3719a9958b9f22e13131643) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Hey Gordon, appreciate the help here.  I made those two changes. I continue to get the same error. Any chance there's somewhere else I should look?

Comment: @johlee . . . You did not tag your question correctly, so you did not get appropriate answers.

Comment: Yes, understood. Learning!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
ALTER TABLE annual_goals
    ADD year_num int;

UPDATE annual_goals
SET year_num=year(date_created);
```